# remote access to virtual machine can't open qgis

Tags: qgis, display, amazon-web-services

I'm currently running a virtual machine on amazon EC2 and planning to do some web-gis service through it. I installed the QGIS remotely but apparently I can't run it from my local machine through ssh, below is the message I got:

```
QGIS starting in non-interactive mode not supported.
You are seeing this message most likely because you have no DISPLAY environment variable set.
```

Anyone could show me a way to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem the other day. I am sure there are better ways of solving it but this is what worked for me.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a digital ocean droplet. I am accessing that through a windows 10 based desktop.

All the below assumes you have QGIS correctly setup on your EC2 server.

As best I can tell QGIS on Ubuntu needs a graphic device to place the GUI. An SSH connection to the machine does not provide that.

I followed this tutorial to setup a VNCViewer (you will have to install both on the Linux system and on your desktop ~ in my case windows):

[Install VNC on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/remote-desktop/install-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04)

I messed it up the first time through skipping a step. So follow it exactly.

If you have followed the instructions in the tutorial you should then have a working Gnome GUI. Then open the console within VNCViewer and in there type in qgis (as you would / did in the SSH console). That should bring up QGIS in the Gnome GUI just as you would have seen it on your desktop.

I found it a bit cumbersome and slow but it worked.

I would be interested to know what better ways there are of doing it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer! I solved the problem by using VNC viewer and VNC server as well, probably the same method.. the problem was the GUI environments, not only for QGIS, other programs also require the GUI environments installed, like some basic text editors , such as sublime text. I will be interested in other ways as well, please let me know if you find anything in the future!

Comment: Great Max_Guo ~ can you just select that answer as being correct so that if anyone else is looking for a solution they will find a workable answer. Or you can just add your own version of the answer and select that. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah I'm glad to :)